# C# , how to use expression to create a list from an user class, and invoke method Add() , ToArray()

Tags: c#, expression

I want write a class , for example : UserData, and it can be used to store any user class to a typed list.

perhaps an user class maybe is

```
   class UserInfo
   {
       public int Id {get;set;}
       ....
   }
```

or

```
   class BookInfo
   {
       public Guid BookId {get;set;}
       public string BookName {get;set;}
       ...
   }
```

The `UserData` class likes

```
    internal class UserData
    {
        private readonly bool _isCollection;

        private readonly Type _userEntityType;

        private Expression _list;

        private someDelegeAdd _add;

        private someDelegeToArray _ToArray;

        public UserData(bool isCollection, Type userEntityType)
        {
            _isCollection = isCollection;
            _userEntityType = userEntityType;
            Make();
        }

        private void Make()
        {
            var genericListType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(_userEntityType);
            _list = Expression.New(genericListType);

            var addDefinition = genericListType.GetMethod("Add", new[] { _userEntityType });
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(_userEntityType);
            var addMethodExp = Expression.Call(_list, addDefinition, parameter);

            _add = Expression.Lambda<Action>(addMethodExp, parameter).Compile(); <-- Action

        }

        internal void Add(object data)
        {
            _add??
        }

        internal object GetValue()
        {
            return _isCollection ? _list?? : _ToArray?? ;
        }

    }
```

I have searched for a long time on the web, there are only Func<T,X> as delege, how to use an Action of any type? and how to use ToArray()?

---update---

using example

```
   if (!cache.Contains(userEntityType))
   {
       var userData = new UserData(false, userEntityType);
       ...
   }
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that you are using means too complicated for the job: Do you *really* need `Expression` and `Expression.Lambda`?? If you want to store lists of arbitrary types you typically use "simple" templates. It would help if you gave an example of code *using* your class; then we know what you actually want to do.

Comment: the `_userEntityType` does not change in your instance of the `UserData` class. Why do you make this more complicated? You could use `List<_userEntityType>`

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thanks for remiding. i post an update.

Comment: @SebastianSiemens, the userEntityType is not known as T

Comment: Just use Action<object> and use cast in the expression(parameter will be object and you need to cast it to given type before calling add in expression)

Comment: also `Action` doesn't make sens as it doesnt take parameters ... it's like `void Method()`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I8ZDGk

Comment: @goldii I may be a bit dense, but I don't understand what your snippet is trying to achieve. What is `cache`? Shouldn't the after `new UserData(false, userEntityType);` the cache contain an entry for `userEntityType`? How is that achieved? What is `userEntityType`?  It would be good to see more code.

Comment: He try to do it dynamic to find out that it doesn't make sens because types will be not define at compile time and similar solution can be achive using generics

Comment: @Selvin, Thanks very much. that's what i want.

Comment: IMHO, If you can solve most of your problem using generics, do that first. If you still need to use that solution in a location where you can't use generics, then use a small amount of reflection to call your generic solution. It's a waste of time and effort to attempt to solve the entire problem using reflection & expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

based on @Selvin 's post https://dotnetfiddle.net/I8ZDGk. I did two tests. And the tests showed Expression is fastter than interface invoke.

--- test1 ---

```
        private void TestExpressionOrHelper()
        {
            var te = new TestExpression(typeof(UserInfo));
            var th = new MuchMuchSimpler(typeof(UserInfo));

            long teTotal = 0;
            long thTotal = 0;

            var userData = new UserInfo[100 * 100 * 100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100 * 100; i++)
            {
                userData[i]= Generate(i);
            }

            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            {
                te.Clear();
                th.Clear();

                Debug.WriteLine($"--> 第{k + 1}次循环");
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100 * 100; i++)
                {
                    te.Add(userData[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                teTotal += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100 * 100; i++)
                {
                    th.Add(userData[i]);
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                thTotal += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"使用expression表达式, 总耗时{teTotal}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"使用接口表达式, 总耗时{thTotal}");
        }
```

the result

```
--> 第1次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 16
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 12
--> 第2次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第3次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第4次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第5次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第6次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第7次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第8次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第9次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第10次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第11次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第12次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第13次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第14次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第15次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第16次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第17次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第18次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第19次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第20次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第21次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第22次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第23次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第24次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第25次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第26次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 12
--> 第27次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第28次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第29次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第30次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第31次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第32次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第33次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第34次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第35次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第36次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第37次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第38次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第39次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第40次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第41次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第42次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第43次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第44次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第45次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第46次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第47次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第48次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第49次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第50次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第51次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第52次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第53次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第54次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第55次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第56次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第57次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第58次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第59次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第60次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第61次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第62次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第63次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第64次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第65次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第66次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第67次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第68次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第69次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第70次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第71次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第72次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第73次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第74次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第75次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第76次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第77次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第78次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 10
--> 第79次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第80次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第81次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第82次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第83次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第84次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第85次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第86次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 5
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第87次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第88次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第89次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第90次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第91次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第92次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 9
--> 第93次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第94次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第95次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第96次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第97次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
--> 第98次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 7
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第99次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8
--> 第100次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 6
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 8

使用expression表达式, 总耗时 637    <<<----
使用接口,             总耗时 798    <<<----
```

--- test2 ---

```
        private void TestExpressionOrHelper()
        {
            var te = new TestExpression(typeof(UserInfo));
            var th = new MuchMuchSimpler(typeof(UserInfo));

            long teTotal = 0;
            long thTotal = 0;

            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)
            {
                te.Clear();
                th.Clear();

                Debug.WriteLine($"--> 第{k + 1}次循环");
                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100 * 100; i++)
                {
                    te.Add(Generate(i));
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                teTotal += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                sw.Restart();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100 * 100 * 100; i++)
                {
                    th.Add(Generate(i));
                }
                sw.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
                thTotal += sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }

            Debug.WriteLine($"使用expression表达式, 总耗时{teTotal}");
            Debug.WriteLine($"使用接口表达式, 总耗时{thTotal}");
        }
```

the result

```
--> 第1次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 518
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 399
--> 第2次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 373
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 389
--> 第3次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 370
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
--> 第4次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 349
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 359
--> 第5次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 338
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 370
--> 第6次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 339
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 363
--> 第7次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 341
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 357
--> 第8次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 339
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
--> 第9次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 332
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 348
--> 第10次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 348
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 372
--> 第11次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 341
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 379
--> 第12次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 338
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 360
--> 第13次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 341
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 333
--> 第14次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 345
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 353
--> 第15次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 325
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 380
--> 第16次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 341
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 348
--> 第17次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 349
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 365
--> 第18次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 342
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 343
--> 第19次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 339
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 386
--> 第20次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 351
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
--> 第21次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 350
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 359
--> 第22次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 348
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 360
--> 第23次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 343
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 360
--> 第24次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 356
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 369
--> 第25次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 342
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
--> 第26次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 346
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 372
--> 第27次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 341
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 394
--> 第28次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 353
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 372
--> 第29次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 334
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 381
--> 第30次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 329
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 376
--> 第31次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 336
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 378
--> 第32次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 344
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
--> 第33次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 337
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 394
--> 第34次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 334
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 359
--> 第35次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 365
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 362
--> 第36次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 411
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 361
--> 第37次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 348
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 407
--> 第38次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 382
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 394
--> 第39次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 379
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 390
--> 第40次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 370
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 397
--> 第41次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 392
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
--> 第42次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 384
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 400
--> 第43次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 407
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 370
--> 第44次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 454
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 466
--> 第45次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 429
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 480
--> 第46次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 432
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 480
--> 第47次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 451
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 496
--> 第48次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 434
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 413
--> 第49次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 372
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 410
--> 第50次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 381
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 408
--> 第51次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 369
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 403
--> 第52次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 378
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 416
--> 第53次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 397
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 425
--> 第54次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 374
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 412
--> 第55次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 366
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 412
--> 第56次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 367
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 416
--> 第57次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 420
--> 第58次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 404
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 404
--> 第59次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 374
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 407
--> 第60次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 421
--> 第61次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 407
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 420
--> 第62次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 376
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 409
--> 第63次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 410
--> 第64次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 413
--> 第65次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 367
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 425
--> 第66次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 405
--> 第67次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 366
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 379
--> 第68次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 394
--> 第69次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 366
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 405
--> 第70次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 404
--> 第71次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 378
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 406
--> 第72次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 378
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 447
--> 第73次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 446
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 444
--> 第74次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 386
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 420
--> 第75次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 370
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 396
--> 第76次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 374
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 418
--> 第77次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 379
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 405
--> 第78次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 383
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 402
--> 第79次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 384
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 407
--> 第80次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 381
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 423
--> 第81次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 406
--> 第82次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 424
--> 第83次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 358
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 405
--> 第84次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 436
--> 第85次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 384
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 421
--> 第86次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 377
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 403
--> 第87次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 395
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 392
--> 第88次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 395
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 414
--> 第89次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 375
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 411
--> 第90次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 392
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 437
--> 第91次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 391
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
--> 第92次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 409
--> 第93次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 390
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 414
--> 第94次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 368
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 409
--> 第95次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 387
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 425
--> 第96次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 392
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 396
--> 第97次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 405
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 408
--> 第98次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 382
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 422
--> 第99次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 376
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 419
--> 第100次循环
使用expression表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 383
使用接口表达式，加载 100万数据 , 耗时 412

使用expression表达式, 总耗时 37334    <<<----
使用接口,             总耗时 39808    <<<----

测试数据，每次 100万条，包含创建数据，调用Add方法
```